# Form validation inside iFrame Colorbox, how to OPEN href URL in parents page and close Colorbox.

Tags: jquery, validation, colorbox

I've been spending too many hours on this and yet can't figure out. Trying to open form submit page from the  into the parents.page when the form pass the validation. This is what we got so far, it did the job but i just don't like the fact that we have to put "window.parent.location.href="/page1.hmtl";" ... which technically don't really submit the form. This code is INSIDE the iframe colorbox that being called.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#formResultQuote").validate({
          rules: {
              rqResult: {
                  required: true,
                  minlength:1
              }
          },
          messages: {
              rqResult: {
                  required: 'Please select one of the saved quotes.'
              }
          },
          errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
              if (element.attr('name') == 'rqResult') {
              error.appendTo(element.parents().find('.rqResultError'));
          parent.$.colorbox.resize({height:580});
          },
         submitHandler: function() {
         if ($('#formResultQuote').valid()) {
         parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
         window.parent.location.href="/page1.hmtl";
         }
       }                  
    });
});
```

basic HTML on this page pretty much like this :

```
<form name="formResultQuote" id="formResultQuote" action="/page1.html" method="post">

<input name="rqResult" id="core" type="radio" class="radioCircle" validate="required:true, minlength:2"/>
<input name="rqResult" id="core" type="radio" class="radioCircle"/></div>
<input name="rqResult" id="core" type="radio" class="radioCircle"/></div>

<input type="submit" value="Retrieve your quote." id="regularSubmitBtn" name="Retrieve_a_Quote" tabindex="27" class="rqSubmitBtn" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
window.parent.location.href="/page1.hmtl";
```

You could try this:

```
parent.jQuery('document').bind('cbox_closed', function(){
    location.href="/page1.hmtl";
});
parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
```